# how to catch the MultipleObjectsReturned error in django

Tags: python, django, exception

Is it possible to catch the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error in Django?

I do a searchquery and if there are more than one objects I want that the first in the list will be taken so I tried this:

```
try:
    Location.objects.get(name='Paul')
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    Location.objects.get(name='Paul')[0]
```

However, it exists in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/) though

> global variable MultipleObjectsReturned does not exist

Comment: If I am not mistaken the exception is a propery of the model. Since that variable doesn't exist error seems to lead me to believe so.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned

Comment: However, I suggest using filter, which returns a queryset then you can take the first item in the query set using indexing. Get is for returning 1 actual object. So  you don't have to deal with error checking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't the best practice. You can technically do this without using exceptions. Did you intend to use `Location` and `Car` in this example?

You can do this:

```
Location.objects.filter(name='Paul').order_by('id').first()
```

I strongly suggest you read the Django QuerySet API reference.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/

To answer your question about where the exception exists -- you can always access these QuerySet exceptions on the model itself. E.g. `Location.DoesNotExist` and `Location.MultipleObjectsReturned`. You don't need to import them if you already have the model imported.

Comment: yeah true! sorry, meant Location both times. Why is using exceptions not the best practice?

Comment: Then what you probably want is just `Location.objects.filter(name='Paul').order_by('id').first()`. It returns None if there isn't a record with that name. I updated the answer. Using exceptions in this case is unneccessary. Instead of causing an exception to be thrown, you can still have a happy path without raising any errors.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the question.

Comment: "This isn't the best practice." Are you sure catching the exception isn't best practices? I think it might be best practice in Python. According to "EAFP" in https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html, I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/32173014/2573242 is the correct answer here.

Comment: It doesn't work in older versions of Django like 1.5. Using first() gives AttributeError.
I had to import MultipleObjectsReturned instead.

Answer (score 60):

Use a filter:

```
Location.objects.filter(name='Paul').first()
```

Or import the exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned
...
try:
    Location.objects.get(name='Paul')
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    Location.objects.filter(name='Paul').first()
```

Comment: **Note**: `Location.objects.get(name='Paul')[0]` will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` again. Use `Location.objects.filter(name='Paul').first()` instead.

Answer (score 48):

This is more pythonic way to do it.

```
try:
    Location.objects.get(name='Paul')
except Location.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    Location.objects.filter(name='Paul')[0]
```

Comment: You mean `filter`, but at least it does answer how to catch the exception.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes it filters or return object according to query. get return object whereas .filter returns queryset.

Comment: @VaseemAhmedKhan The answer should be updated to do `Location.objects.filter(name='Paul')[0]`, otherwise the except block will result in the same exception being thrown. You need a queryset because that contains the logic about _which_ object to return, for instance `Location.objects.get(name='Paul').order_by('age')[0]` will return the youngest Paul in the database. This is how you return the correct Paul, according to your business logic.

Comment: @AlanSE No, the exception block will not throw the same exception. It might throw a `DoesNotExist` exception, but not `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

Answer (score 5):

Use get when you know there is only one object that matches your query. If no items match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception. If multiple items matches the query, get() will raise a MultipleObjectsReturned exception. Use get() like this:

```
try:
  one_entry = Entry.objects.get(blog=2000)
except Entry.DoesNotExist:
  # query did not match to any item.
  pass
except Entry.MultipleObjectsReturned:
  # query matched multiple items.
  pass
else:
  # query matched to just one item
  print(one_entry)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, even if we use `MyModel.objects.get_or_create(...)`, there is still chances for **creation of multiple instances** due to **race conditions**. So, when we have to use `MyModel.objects.get` or `MyModel.objects.get_or_create`, we still have to expect return of multiple objects.

To handle this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned

try:
    obj,is_created=MyModel.objects.get_or_create(....)
except MultipleObjectsReturned as e:
    # handle the case as you need here
    pass
```